# Ctrl + Shift for language change without killing terminal

Tags: 20.04, shortcuts

I have just installed Ubuntu and even didn't have enough time to solve usual grub problems. Suddenly I noticed, that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't change languages. I tried to fix it from settings - they didn't react on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>at all. OK, tried usual gnome-tweaks method - then terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> shortcut was shadowed.
So question is
How can I set language change on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and not shadow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C/V</kbd> combination at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by "*didn't have enough time to solve usual grub problems*" - your installation failed or was otherwise unsuccessful? You might want to solve this problem first, in case it is related.  A borked installation can sometimes reveal weird problems later on

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `gnome-tweaks` for this. Run `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` in terminal to install `gnome-tweaks`.

1. Open `gnome-tweaks`, from app drawer.
2. Select `keyboard & mouse` in the left column.

[image]
3. Click on the `Additional Layout Options` and scroll down to `Switching to another layout`.

[image]

4. Check the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> option, and uncheck any other selected option, and we are done.

Comment: That's the exact form of action after which I can't use Ctrl+Shift+C/V shortcut in terminal

Comment: @KingCake So even after selecting Ctrl + Shift, it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome-tweaks (apt install gnome-tweaks), run just installed Tweaks, select Keyboard&Mouse->Additional Layout Options and choose shutcut ctl+shift or something else.